# How to get into the "non spam" territory as a new website/server?

Tags: email, server, spam

Well we are just in the process of releasing a website live, first for a select few testers and soon (plan is around summer) for everyone.

Now everything is working, and I just started the last sprint to do some integration testing of the complete components. During these tests I notice that our emails for account verification (and other emails) are consistently being marked as "spam".

Now we "own" the IP address already for several years, unused though. - The hostmask we own since last summer (shortly after the domain `.app` was released, so unlikely that someone else owned it for 1-2 months before we got it).

How can I our rank up before we release the first public version? As this would almost be a killing "feature" and would destroy our website before it is even launched. (A lot depends on email-interaction).

We have already set up DKIM, DMARC and SPF correctly.

Comment: The first step is to run something like SpamAssassin on mail received from your domain. If it marks it as spam, it will list all the reasons why.